# What does this Scala syntax mean - a value definition followed by open brace and indented stuff?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to decipher somebody else's code. The following appeared in a Scala trait. This isn't its exact content, I flattened out some of the detail to make it more general (it had some extra lines before the closed-curly-bracket incorporating a zipWithIndex method, and some other pattern matching stuff.) My main concern was that I am not familiar with this concept; a value definition that begins with an open-curly-bracket and then a bunch of indented stuff.

```
val example: ExampleType = {
    val anOtherExample = "String"
    val yetAnOtherExample = 22
    new ExampleType(anOtherExample, yetAnOtherExample)
}
```

Comment: the lines before the closed-curly-bracket - which likely form an expression of type `ExampleType` - are the crucial part, because a block in Scala is an expression, not a statement like in Java.

Comment: Thanks (and thanks to the other answerers), I think I understand this a bit better now. I added an extra line which I think reflects your comments, that I had omitted before for lack of understanding. Here, `example` will be a new instance of the `ExampleType`, and the indented stuff will be instructions on how to create this object from more primitive types (Strings and Integers). No?

Comment: Exactly. the block may contain any instructions, but will usually only contain code necessary to derive the expression's value.

Answer (score 2):

Having experience with C-like languages and/or Java, you may be used to the fact that curly braces `{}` denote a block of *code* - i.e. just a set of instructions that will be invoked.

Scala is different on this part, because in Scala almost everything is an expression, i.e. almost everything evaluates to some value and therefore can be assigned to a `val`, passed as an argument, etc.

Therefore, a block of code in Scala is not just a sequence of instructions, but a valid expression that can be assigned and passed around. Block of code evaluates to the last expression in that block, i.e.

```
val x: Int = {
  doSomething()
  doSomethingElse()
  42
}
```

In the above example, `x` will have 42 assigned as its value.

Comment: Thanks. Is the point of this that `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse` might help us arrive at the number `42`, which we want assigned to `x`?

Comment: That, and to show that a block can have side effects even if used in an expression context.

Comment: @bibblybobbly Yes, I often use this "pattern" to perform complex initialization, it helps to prevent local namespace from pollution.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    val anotherExample = "String"
    val yetAnotherExample = 22
}
```

This is called *block*. It is evaluated to its last statement. Here the last statement is an assignment  `val yetAnotherExample = 22` which is of type `Unit` in Scala. So your code will not compile if your `ExampleType` is not the same type as `Unit`.